# loop over a list of instances to do yum update failed with exit status 126

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, yum, aws-ssm

I need to automate yum update across a list of instances, I tried something like `aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript"  --parameters 'commands=["sudo yum -y update"]' --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=<target instance id>" --timeout-seconds 600` in my local terminal (MFA enabled, logged in as IAM user, can list all ec2 instance under all regions by `aws ec2 describe-instances`) got the output with `StatusDetails": "Pending"` and the update never took place.

I checked the ssm log after starting an ssm session on the target instance

```
2021-12-08 00:03:32 INFO [ssm-agent-worker] [MessagingDeliveryService] Sending reply {
  "additionalInfo": {
    "agent": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "name": "amazon-ssm-agent",
      "os": "",
      "osver": "1",
      "ver": ""
    },
    "dateTime": "2021-12-08T00:03:32.061Z",
    "runId": "",
    "runtimeStatusCounts": {
      "Failed": 1
    }
  },
  "documentStatus": "InProgress",
  "documentTraceOutput": "",
  "runtimeStatus": {
    "aws:runShellScript": {
      "status": "Failed",
      "code": 126,
      "name": "aws:runShellScript",
      "output": "\n----------ERROR-------\nsh: /var/lib/amazon/ssm/i-074cfdd5be7fe517b/document/orchestration/2d917bcc-fc6e-4e4b-b500-cc2e2b7bd4d6/awsrunShellScript/0.awsrunShellScript/_script.sh: Permission denied\nfailed to run commands: exit status 126",
      "startDateTime": "2021-12-08T00:03:32.024Z",
      "endDateTime": "2021-12-08T00:03:32.061Z",
      "outputS3BucketName": "",
      "outputS3KeyPrefix": "",
      "stepName": "",
      "standardOutput": "",
      "standardError": "sh: /var/lib/amazon/ssm/i-074cfdd5be7fe517b/document/orchestration/2d917bcc-fc6e-4e4b-b500-cc2e2b7bd4d6/awsrunShellScript/0.awsrunShellScript/_script.sh: Permission denied\nfailed to run commands: exit status 126"
    }
  }
}
```

I checked the directory permission

```
ls -al /var/lib/amazon/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   17 Jul 26 23:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 root root 4096 Aug  6 18:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   80 Aug  7 00:03 ssm
```

and further one level down

```
ls -al /var/lib/amazon/ssm
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  80 Aug  7 00:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  17 Jul 26 23:53 ..
drw------- 2 root root   6 Aug  7 00:03 daemons
drw------- 8 root root 111 Dec  8 00:03 i-074cfdd5be7fe517b
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  39 Aug  7 00:03 ipc
drw------- 3 root root  23 Aug  7 00:03 localcommands
```

I also tried more basic commands like `echo HelloWorld` and got the same 126 error.

Comment: did you enable logs for ssm command and check it out?

Comment: Can be many reasons. Sadly you haven't provided much information about your setup. For example, does run command work from AWS console?